# Kestrel on Windows no response

Tags: c#, asp.net-core-mvc, kestrel-http-server

I have an self hosted mvc project using Kestrel as http server.
On some machines ranging from Windows Server 2016 to Windows 10 for some reason there is no response received when trying to access application over the http.
The browser just hangs in **waiting for server address**.
As i said this have occurred just on 1% of installations but i need to figure it out.
I have tried to stripping my configuration to minimal as possible and still no response from server, console logger also shows no records as if nothing happens so there is no errors or indication of anything going wrong on startup or when requests are made.

Here is my WebHostBuilder code

```
       var hostBuilder = new WebHostBuilder()
                    .UseStartup<WebStartup>()
                    .UseKestrel(kestrelOptions =>
                    {
                        //listen on configured web port
                        kestrelOptions.ListenAnyIP(WEB_PORT, options=>
                        {
                        });

                        if (HTTPS_ENABLE)
                        {
                            kestrelOptions.Listen(IPAddress.Any, HTTPS_PORT, listenOpt =>
                            {
                                if (string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(HTTPS_PFX_FILE) || !File.Exists(HTTPS_PFX_FILE))
                                {
                                    TraceInitMessage($"PFX file not found.");
                                }
                                else if (string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(HTTPS_PFX_PASSWORD))
                                {
                                    TraceInitMessage($"PFX file password is invalid.");
                                }
                                else
                                {
                                    listenOpt.UseHttps(HTTPS_PFX_FILE, HTTPS_PFX_PASSWORD, httpsOptions =>
                                    {
                                        httpsOptions.SslProtocols = System.Security.Authentication.SslProtocols.Default;
                                    });
                                }
                            });
                        }
                    });
```

If i check the process i can see that there is a listening connection and once browser connects there is an established connection, if browser window closed connection goes to close wait state.

So is there any way i can figure at which place in the where the problem starts in the whole pipeline ?

Comment: Which browser are you using? Looking for the error message you provided brings up this SO thread and a bunch of SNTP links.

Comment: The behavior is same in all browsers. Calling a WEB Api endpoint with Postman behaves exactly the same.
I am not an expert but it seem on browser side the request never times out, hope that info is also useful.

Comment: All browsers return the exact same error message? That seems doubtful. Are you seeing that error message from kestrel or IIS console or logs?

Comment: There is no error message just "waiting for host" i can clearly see that connection is accepted on server BUT nothing happens , console logging also display zero info as nothing happens.

Comment: Yes, it's just the exact phrasing of an error message is critical to receiving relevant responses on SO.

Answer (score 1):

So the problem it seems that some of the dependent dlls did not have a assembly binding redirects. 
Adding following configuration resolved the problem

```
      <dependentAssembly>
    <assemblyIdentity name="System.Threading.Overlapped" publicKeyToken="b03f5f7f11d50a3a" culture="neutral" />
    <bindingRedirect oldVersion="0.0.0.0-0.0.0.0" newVersion="4.1.0.0" />
  </dependentAssembly>
  <dependentAssembly>
    <assemblyIdentity name="System.Net.Sockets" publicKeyToken="b03f5f7f11d50a3a" culture="neutral" />
    <bindingRedirect oldVersion="0.0.0.0-0.0.0.0" newVersion="4.2.0.0" />
  </dependentAssembly>
```